# Date formatter in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I have a requirement where i have to store different date and time with time zones.
I have used ZonedDateTime of java 8 .

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");
ZonedDateTime zt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);

System.out.println(zt.toString());
```

My problem is I want to store this in java.util.Date format.
I used DateTimeFormatter

```
 DateTimeFormatter dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
dtf.format(zt);
```

Until here it works fine this gives me the required date in string format now when i try to convert this to java.util.Date using simple date format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(dtf.format(zt)));
```

I get output as Sat Mar 12 00:44:10 IST 2016 but i want output as 2016-03-11T14:14:10-05:00 in java.util.Date type. Can somebody suggest where am i going wrong?

Comment: Currently you're calling `Date.toString()` in the last line. At that point, you're back to the same point as many, many other questions - a `java.util.Date` doesn't store a time zone or a format.

Comment: (I'd strongly avoid using `java.util.Date`, if you possibly can - use the `java.time` types as widely as you can.)

Comment: Why `Date` if you use Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ZonedDateTime > Instant > Date

Best to avoid the old date-time classes including java.util.Date. But if you must, you can convert. Call the new [`from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method on the old java.util.Date class.

For that you need an `Instant` a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myZonedDateTime.toInstant();
java.util.Date juDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

To go the other direction:

```
Instant instant = juDate.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a wrong way this is the corrected code

sdf.format(sdf.parse(val)) this the right way.

```
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");
    ZonedDateTime zt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);

    System.out.println(zt.toString());
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    String val = dtf.format(zt);
    System.out.println(val);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    //String dateStr = zt.format(sdf);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(val)));
```

Comment: This is giving the desired output but its in the string format. I want to store the output  2016-03-12T02:44:28-0500 in Date format.

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli The answer is correct so you should accept it. And you need to understand that an object of type `java.util.Date` does NOT carry any format information. The canonical output of its method `toString()` cannot be configured to another format.

Comment: Remember that SImpleDateFormat is not safe in case you have multi-threaded app.