# Properly working with dates that comes as a string value and compare them

Tags: java, string, date, formatting, epoch

In my program, I have a bunch of strings that represent dates and looks like this:

```
String someDate1 = "abcd-2020-02-19t10:23:31.180z";
String someDate2 = "xyz-2020-02-22t10:03:31.111z";
String someDate2 = "blablabla-2020-06-15t11:13:31.181z";
```

Let's take "*someDate1*" for example, I've managed to trim those strings so I'll end up having only the date by doing this for example:

```
System.out.println(someDate1.substring(someDate1.length() - 24).substring(0, 19));
```

output:

```
2020-02-19t10:23:31
```

now, I want to determine whether or not this date at the output is older than seven days or not.

let's say I keep the string above in a list, so all I want is simply to know if my date is older than a week or not something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String someDate1 = "abcd-2020-02-19t10:23:31.180z";
    List<String> datesList = new ArrayList<>();
    datesList.add(someDate1);
    ...//adding others too

    datesList.forEach(date -> {
        if (isDateOlder(date)) {
            System.out.println(date + " - this is more than 7 days old, it has been more than a week!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(date + " - it has NOT been more than a week since this date!");
        }
    });
}


static boolean isDateOlder(String date) { 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");
    String afterTrimming = date.substring(date.length() - 24).substring(0, 19).replace("t", "-");

    try {
        Date afterFormatParse = formatter.parse(afterTrimming);

        LocalDate weekAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7); //cool thing you can do, but i'm not using it
        System.out.println("a week ago : " + weekAgo); //it seems useful but i don't really use it because I saw I can't compare "Date" with LocalDate

        long rn = new Date().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        long weekInMillis = 604800000;
        long oneWeekAgo = rn - weekInMillis;


        if (afterFormatParse.toInstant().toEpochMilli() <= oneWeekAgo) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

The bottom line is, it works, but this seems very naive/wasteful and I'm sure there's a more clever way...
so basically my main question is:

It's too bad that LocalDate doesn't have "toDate()" method so you would be able to compare between the two when you need to, in the end, I used a 'fixed epoch" in a variable to represent a week, which is very naive. I'd like to hear if you guys have a prettier way to represent a date minus a week like LocalDate offers and at the same time, a way to compare between one another?

- *note:* I've also taken a try with isBefore() like so:

  afterFormatParse.toInstant().isBefore(LocalDate.now().minusDays(7))
  but it can't be done because "LocalDate.now().minusDays(7)" is LocalDate type and not Instant type, and when Using Date i don't have the ".minusDays(7)" ability anymore
- *note 2*: in reality, my strings sometimes starts with "add-vvd-sfsf-...." or more that's why I'm trimming from the end

thanks a lot.

Comment: why not use [isBefore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

Comment: *FYI:* You're using the new Java 8 `LocalDate` and `Instant` objects, but also using the old flawed `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Don't use both, only use the newer API.

Comment: hey, @ScaryWombat pls see the note I edited.

Comment: In addition to @Andreas comment see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948724/2310289

Comment: @Andreas, of course, I've just tried to sort of showing you everything I tried to use in my example but this is definitely not the final result I'm gonna use

Comment: @Andreas and to your second comment, it saves me a ".replace(...)" for the trimming tnx:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2020-02-19t10:23:31.180z` is in a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, natively supported by the Java 8+ Time API, so there is no need to use a custom format pattern.

As such, to check if the date is more than 7 days in the past, to the fractional second, you can do it like this:

```java
static boolean isDateOlder(String dateStr) {
    Instant date = Instant.parse(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf('-') + 1));
    Instant weekAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(7).toInstant();
    return date.isBefore(weekAgo);
}
```

If you want to **ignore** the time part *and* the time zone offset (compare date parts only), you can do it like this:

```java
static boolean isDateOlder(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf('-') + 1),
                                     DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    LocalDate weekAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7);
    return date.isBefore(weekAgo);
}
```

To adjust the UTC time zone offset (e.g. `Z`) in the input to the local time zone, then compare pure dates (in case time zone shift crosses midnight), you can do it like this:

```java
static boolean isDateOlder(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = Instant.parse(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf('-') + 1))
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .toLocalDate();
    LocalDate weekAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7);
    return date.isBefore(weekAgo);
}
```

Or more leniently, supporting time zones other than `Z`:

```java
static boolean isDateOlder(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf('-') + 1))
                                  .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                  .toLocalDate();
    LocalDate weekAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7);
    return date.isBefore(weekAgo);
}
```

Comment: great! this is just what I needed:
Instant aWeekAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(7).toInstant();

Comment: sidenote: in reality, my strings sometimes starts with "add-vvd-sfsf-...." or more that's why I'm trimming from the end